# The maximal difference between a function and translates of itself

Tags: real-analysis

*Note: We view the sphere $S^1$ as $[0,1]$ with the endpoints identified, and equip it with its usual addition structure, and Lebesgue measure.*

**Question:** Does there exist an absolute constant $C > 0$ such that for all $L^1$ functions $f: S^1 \to \mathbb R$,

$$\sup_{t \in S^1} \int_{S^1} |f(x + t) - f(x)| \, dx \geq C\int_{S^1} \left|f(x) - \left(\int_{S_1} f(y) \, dy\right) \right| \,dx\text{?}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the condition $\int_{S^1}dx=1$ and Jensen's inequality, we have
$$\sup_{t\in S^1} \int_{S^1}dx\,|f(x + t)-f(x)|
\ge\int_{S^1}dt\, \int_{S^1}dx\,|f(x + t)-f(x)| \\
=\int_{S^1}dx\, \int_{S^1}dt\,|f(x)-f(x + t)|
\ge\int_{S^1}dx\, \Big|f(x)-\int_{S^1}dt\,f(x + t)\Big| \\ 
=\int_{S^1}dx\, \Big|f(x)-\int_{S^1}dy\,f(y)\Big|. $$
So, your conjectured inequality holds with $C=1$. $\quad\Box$

Comment: $+1$, is $C=1$ optimal?

Comment: @mathworker21 : This is a good question. I don't think that $C=1$ is optimal. Do you have an idea about the optimal value?

Comment: @NateRiver It's the triangle inequality for integrals: $$\int_{S^1} \left| f(x) - \int_{S^1} f(x+t)dt \right| dx \le \int_{S^1} \int_{S^1} |f(x)-f(x+t)| dt dx.$$

Comment: Oh.. so it is haha

Comment: The best constant is 1. This is seen best for measures: just take  a $\delta$ at any point. For any $t$, the total variation of the difference between $\delta$ and $\delta_t$ is 2 as well as that of $\delta-1$. For functions, one approximates the $\delta$ with $\epsilon^{-1} \chi (0, \epsilon)$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune : Thank you for your comment, which finalizes the matter.